# get my videos duration with youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am using this youtube api sample, to get duration of my uploaded videos. In this Resource representation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet I can see structure of json, but can't get this part

[image]

Currently I am managed to get contentDetails with 'videoPublishedAt' it looks like this `({u'videoPublishedAt': u'2013-03-13T00:05:41.000Z', u'videoId': u'6PKHl3Kvppk'})`

I added 'contentDetails' to 'part'

```
  playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    playlistId=uploads_list_id,
    part="snippet,contentDetails",
    maxResults=50
  )
```

And then changed `video_id = playlist_item["contentDetails"]` in last section `while playlistitems_list_request:`

But `video_id = playlist_item["contentDetails"]["duration"]` give **KeyError: 'duration'**

Here is full code without authentication part and imports. Full version could be found here https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/my_uploads.py

```
# Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the
# authenticated user's channel.
channels_response = youtube.channels().list(
  mine=True,
  part="contentDetails"
).execute()

for channel in channels_response["items"]:
  # From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
  # of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
  uploads_list_id = channel["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]

  print "Videos in list %s" % uploads_list_id

  # Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
  playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    playlistId=uploads_list_id,
    part="snippet,contentDetails",
    maxResults=50
  )

  while playlistitems_list_request:
    playlistitems_list_response = playlistitems_list_request.execute()

    # Print information about each video.
    for playlist_item in playlistitems_list_response["items"]:
      title = playlist_item["snippet"]["title"]
      video_id = playlist_item["contentDetails"]
      print "%s (%s)" % (title, video_id)

    playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
      playlistitems_list_request, playlistitems_list_response)

  print
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to get the duration. I'll just give you the Try-it using the [Youtube API Explorer Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=contentDetails&id=jMeSar7_ECE&fields=etag%252CeventId%252Citems%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination%252CvisitorId&_h=2&) and just implement it on your code.

I supplied the parameters for id which is the videoId of your youtube vid and contentDetails for part.

A successful response returned the duration of my video along with other metadata:

```
  "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT1M28S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "projection": "rectangular",
    "hasCustomThumbnail": false
   }
```

Here, it's 1 minute and 28 seconds. 
  Check [Youtube Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) for additional reference.